# Bootstrap 3.1.1 css files not loading in windows 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using bootstrap for a few design works for a website. 
I have been using the Bootstrap CDN link for the css and JS files,
When i am coding in Linux/Ubuntu , they work just fine. 
But when trying out the code in Windows 8, the css files are not loading at all. 
I even tried downloading the bootstrap files and linked the css files from the home directory, still the result is the same.

P.s: Do note that the same file when run in ubuntu works just fine, tried googling the issue, but could not find any similar issue. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: can you show us hows you applied the css and js into your file? If possible then also provide the directory structure as well.

Comment: what does the OS have to do with it? Is it different browsers?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem yesterday with loading jQuery from Google and stylesheets from a URL. The console in chrome, kept throwing an error saying it could not retrieve the file.

My solution was to run the browser "As administrator". 
Simple right click and select "Run as administrator".